# Don't understand Cannot Coerce type 'closure' Error

Tags: r, functional-programming, closures

I see this is a common issue but I can't understand what to do from reading other posts or trying to understand functional programming which is new to me. Functions are closures in R, encapsulating the environment they were created in? The code I have is:

```
# Remove numbers from text
minus_TextNum <- function(df, new.df){
  new.df <- mutate(df, text = gsub(x = text, pattern = "[0-9]+|\\(.*\\)", replacement = "")) %>%  # and/or whatever's in brackets
    unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word) %>% 
    filter(!word %in% c(stop_words$word, "patient")) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(text = paste(word, collapse = " "))
  return(new.df)
}

minus_TextNum(TidySymptoms)
```

Error is as follows:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `text`. ℹ `text = gsub(x = text, pattern = "[0-9]+|\\(.*\\)", replacement = "")`. x cannot coerce
> type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

I don't understand what type closure is, and this is a simple function that works on a simple dataset I created to test. Problem arises when I use the real-world dataset.

Any feedback appreciated. Reproducible sample below:

```
# Remove numbers and/or anything in brackets

# Test Data
mydata <- data.frame(id = 1:8,
                     text = c("112773 Nissan Micra, Car, (10 pcs)",
                              "112774 Nissan Micra, Car, (10 pcs)",
                              "112775 Nissan Micra, Car, (10 pcs)",
                              "112776 Volkswagon Beetle, Car, (3 pcs)",
                              "112777 Toyota Corolla, Car, (12 pcs)",
                              "112778 Nissan Micra, Car, (10 pcs)",
                              "112779 Toyota Prius, Car, (9 pcs)",
                              "112780 Toyota Corolla, Car, (12 pcs)"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

# remove numbers from text data
data(stop_words)
minus_TextNum <- function(df, new.df){
  new.df <- mutate(df, text = gsub(x = text, pattern = "[0-9]+|\\(.*\\)", replacement = "")) %>%  # and/or whatevers in brackets
    unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word) %>% 
    filter(!word %in% c(stop_words$word, "car")) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(text = paste(word, collapse = " "))
  return(new.df)
}


minus_TextNum(mydata)
```

> dput(head(TidySymptoms, n = 10))
> structure(list(word = c("epiglottis", "swelled", "hinder", "swallowing",
> "pictures", "benadryl", "tylenol", "approximately", "30", "min"
> )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: `minus_TextNum` takes two arguments but you are passing only one? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You did not define the variable `text`. So, R assumes it to be the function `text()` which is used to add text to a plot. And a function can not be interpreted as character. So, `gsub()` can't find a pattern in it. If `text` is a column in your `df`, the correct notation would be `df$text = gsub(x=df$text, pattern....`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You probably don't need `new.df` in your `function((`, as `new.df <-  minus_TextNum(df)` achieves that for you. dput(head(you_data, n = 10)) would be useful here.

Comment: @MartinWettstein well, yes and no. I think you've correctly identified the issue, but inside `dplyr::mutate` the `df$` you suggest is not needed, and will create bugs if there is a `group_by`. Unquoted column names should be used inside `dplyr` functions, without any `df$` prefix.

Comment: In `mutate()`, it might not be required, no. But in `gsub()` it is. That's what's throwing the error.

Comment: @Ronak Shah I thought first arg is input, 2nd arg is output hence I return the same variable. Is this wrong? Also, don't know why it worked on test data, I've added to op if you could take a look?

Comment: @Chris I've added dput output to op. I've removed second arg as thought I needed that as output.

Comment: @MartinWettstein Thank you for explaining that for me, I couldn't see another function possibility in the code but that makes more sense now. I've tried adding the df$text and it throws error of unexpected '}' in'}'

Comment: `TidySymptoms` data has no `id` column in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TidySymptoms` data has no `id` column in it. Assuming it's a mistake and you have that already in your data you can do the following changes in the function.

- There is no need to pass `df.new` to the function.
- The column in `TidySymptoms` is called as `word` but you are using `text` in the function.

Try this code.

```
minus_TextNum <- function(df){

  df.new <- mutate(df, text = gsub(x = word, pattern = "[0-9]+|\\(.*\\)", replacement = "")) %>%  
    unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word) %>% 
    filter(!word %in% c(stop_words$word, "patient")) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(text = paste(word, collapse = " "))
    return(new.df)
}

minus_TextNum(TidySymptoms)
```